How can i change the color of focused button in python-prompt-toolkit
I was working on building a music player in Python using python-prompt-toolkit. I wanted to change the color of the focused button, but I can't quite figure it out. To implement this, I tried looking at the example given at buttons.py.
In the example given on their GitHub, the color given is red, but when I change it for example, to green, it does not change, i.e., remains red. Any help would be appreciated.
style = Style(
    [
        ("left-pane", "bg:#888800 #000000"),
        ("right-pane", "bg:#00aa00 #000000"),
        ("button", "#000000"),
        ("button-arrow", "#000000"),
        ("button focused", "bg:green"),
        ("text-area focused", "bg:#ff0000"),
    ]
)


style = Style.from_dict({
    "left-pane": "bg:#888800 #000000",
    "right-pane": "bg:#00aa00 #000000",
    "button": "#000000",
    "button-arrow": "#000000",
    "button focused": "bg:#00ff00", 
    "text-area focused": "bg:#ff0000",
})

you can try this.

unfortunately, the solution you provided did not work, the focus on the button is still red, is there anything else that could be tried?
